# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()

Tags: flutter

I tried to make a compass for a flutter app.

This idea was to put an image of the compass on the camera preview.

The result seems to be ok:

First, the user has a camera preview with the compass :

[image: Compass over camera preview]

The name of the room can be added.

When the user takes a picture, it makes a screenshot that can be shared:

[image]

Even it seems to work fine, I have the following error message on Android Studio:

```
    E/flutter (29454): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _CompassState#46249(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (29454): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (29454): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (29454): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (29454): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1204:9)
E/flutter (29454): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1239:6)
E/flutter (29454): #2      _CompassState._onData (package:franck_ehrhart/seller/compass.dart:28:29)
E/flutter (29454): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (29454): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (29454): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (29454): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (29454): #7      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:611:14)
E/flutter (29454): #8      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11)
E/flutter (29454): #9      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7)
E/flutter (29454): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (29454): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (29454): #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (29454): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (29454): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (29454): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (29454): #16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (29454): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (29454): #18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (29454): #19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (29454):
```

Here is the source code for the compass:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_compass/flutter_compass.dart';



class Compass extends StatefulWidget {

  Compass({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CompassState createState() => _CompassState();
}

class _CompassState extends State<Compass> {

  double _heading = 0;

  String get _readout => _heading.toStringAsFixed(0) + '°';

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    FlutterCompass.events.listen(_onData);
  }

  void _onData(double x) => setState(() { _heading = x; });

  final TextStyle _style = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5) ,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: CompassPainter(angle: _heading),
        child: Center(child: Text(_readout, style: _style))
    );
  }
}

class CompassPainter extends CustomPainter {

  CompassPainter({ @required this.angle }) : super();

  final double angle;
  double get rotation => -2 * pi * (angle / 360);

  Paint get _brush => new Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 4.0;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {



    Paint circle = _brush
      ..color = Colors.blue.shade800.withOpacity(0.6);

    Paint needle = _brush
      ..color = Colors.lightBlueAccent;

    double radius = min(size.width / 2.2, size.height / 2.2);
    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    Offset start = Offset.lerp(Offset(center.dx, radius), center, .4);
    Offset end = Offset.lerp(Offset(center.dx, radius), center, -2);

    canvas.translate(center.dx, center.dy);
    canvas.rotate(rotation);
    canvas.translate(-center.dx, -center.dy);
    canvas.drawLine(start, end, needle);
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, circle);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Here is the code for the page displaying both camera preview and compass:
[image: Compass over camera preview]

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import'package:franck_ehrhart/camera/preview_compass.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:image_picker_saver/image_picker_saver.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CompassTool extends StatefulWidget {

  // Screenshot
  CompassTool({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CompassToolState createState() => _CompassToolState();
}

class _CompassToolState extends State<CompassTool> {

  // Screenshot
  static GlobalKey screen = new GlobalKey();

  // Camera

  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  String compassPath;



  // Textinput name of room

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  String roomName = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Camera

    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIndex = 0;
        });
        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIndex]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print('No camera available');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error :${err.code}Error message : ${err.message}');
    });

  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.medium);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ORIENTATION PIECES"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent.shade700,
      ),
      //   body: Compass()
      body:

          Container(

          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child:
                    _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                  ),

                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _cameraToggleRowWidget(),
                          _cameraControlWidget(context),
                          Spacer()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 10.0, vertical :5.0),
                    child:  TextField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Nom de la pièce',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Nom de la pièce',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        setState(() {
                          roomName = text;
                          //you can access nameController in its scope to get
                          // the value of text entered as shown below
                          //fullName = nameController.text;
                        }
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),

    );


  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures
  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                _onCapturePressed(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display Camera preview.
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }
    return
      //screenshot
      RepaintBoundary(
        key: screen,
     child: Stack(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Positioned.fill(
          child: new AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: new CameraPreview(controller)),
        ),
        new Positioned.fill(
            child: Compass(
            )
        ),
      ],
    ),
      );
  }





  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraToggleRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
          icon: Icon(
            _getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection),
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 24,
          ),
          label: Text(
            '${lensDirection.toString().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase()}',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
            ),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Camera

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera_solid;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error:${e.code}\nError message : ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);
  }

  void _onCapturePressed(context) async {
    try {
      // Compass
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = screen.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
      ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      final compassPath =
      await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(
          fileData:byteData.buffer.asUint8List() );
      // Camera
      final path =
      join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${DateTime.now()}.png');
      await controller.takePicture(path);

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PreviewCompass(
              imgPath: path,
              compassPath: compassPath,
              roomName: roomName,
            )
        ),
      );

    } catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
  }


  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIndex =
    selectedCameraIndex < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIndex + 1 : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }




}
```

And here is the code for the page displaying the screenshot of the previous screen:

[image]

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// packages screenshot
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';

// Compass



class PreviewCompass extends StatefulWidget{
  final String imgPath;
  final String compassPath;
  final String roomName;

  const PreviewCompass({Key key, this.imgPath, this.compassPath, this.roomName}) : super(key: key);

  //PreviewCompass({this.imgPath,this.roomName});


  @override
  _PreviewCompassState createState() => _PreviewCompassState();

}
class _PreviewCompassState extends State<PreviewCompass>{

  // Screenshot

  File _imageFile;
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Screenshot(
      controller: screenshotController,
      child:
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          title: Text("ORIENTATION PIECE"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent.shade700,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
            flex: 2,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          children: <Widget>[

        new Positioned.fill(child:
        Image.file(File(widget.imgPath),fit: BoxFit.fill,),),

            new Positioned.fill(child:
            Image.file(File(widget.compassPath),fit: BoxFit.fill,),),
              /*
              Expanded(
               // flex: 1,
                child:
                Image.file(File(widget.imgPath),fit: BoxFit.fill,),
              ),

              Align(
               // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child:  Image.file(File(widget.compassPath),fit: BoxFit.fill,),
              ),*/
],
          ),
            ),
              Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 10.0, vertical :5.0),
                  child: ListTile (
                    leading: Icon(
                      FontAwesome.compass,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                    ),
                    title: (
                        Text (widget?.roomName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                              color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Center(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.share,color: Colors.white,),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        _takeScreenshotandShare();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  // Screenshot

  _takeScreenshotandShare() async {
    _imageFile = null;
    screenshotController
        .capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10), pixelRatio: 2.0)
        .then((File image) async {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
      });
      final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      Uint8List pngBytes = _imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
      File imgFile = new File('$directory/screenshot.png');
      imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
      print("File Saved to Gallery");
      await Share.file('Screenshot', 'screenshot.png', pngBytes, 'image/png');
    })
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  }



}
```

Can you please help me with this error ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from here:

```
FlutterCompass.events.listen(_onData);
```

You should store that stream subscription in a variable and cancel it in the dispose method:

```
  StreamSubscription<double> stream;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    stream = FlutterCompass.events.listen(_onData);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much :)