# showModalBottomSheet and Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose() on parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, stateful

**Context:**

I have a modal bottom sheet that pops up, upon selection of Camera/Gallery acquires/selects an image `XFile` and returns it for processing (uploading) done with the help of [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

This is done with a sample line:

```dart
  ListTile(
    onTap: () {

      // definition: Future<XFile?> showCamera(IdPhotoOrientation orientation);
      showCamera(orientation).then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pop<XFile?>(value));
    },
    ...
  ),
```

**Picking an image** with [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) is done by returning the selected `XFile` and processing it on a chained function `_handleFile(XFile, enum)`:

```
return showModalBottomSheet<XFile?>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListBody(
        children: [
          ...
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              showCamera(orientation).then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pop<XFile?>(value));
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.camera),
            title: Text("From Camera"),
          ),
          ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
).then((value) => _handleFile(value, orientation));
```

---

**What is the problem:**

While processing file in `_handle(XFile?, int)`, I need to update the state of the app to show progress bar updates, circular indicators, uploading status, etc.

```
  Future<void> _handleFile(XFile? xfile, int orientation) {
    if (xfile == null) {
      return Future.value();
    }

    // store locally with Uploading Status
    var imageService = locator<ImageService>();
    setState(() {                                              <-------- offending line (ui_partner_registration_id_photos.dart:103:5)
      remoteImageStatus[xfile] = UploadStatus.Uploading;
      images[orientation] = xfile;
    });

    // Upload and update result / error
    return imageService.uploadIDPhoto(File(xfile.path), orientation).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        idPhotos[orientation] = value;
        remoteImageStatus[xfile] = UploadStatus.Done;
      });
      print("Uploaded [${xfile.path}]");
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print("Error uploading image");
      print(stackTrace);
      setState(() {
        remoteImageStatus[xfile] = UploadStatus.Error;
      });
    });
  }
```

**Why is this a problem?**

[setState() cannot be called on a stateful widget that is no longer visible/active/in-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340116/setstate-called-after-dispose/53815277%60) which is now the case for the `showModalBottomSheet`. That being said, after calling `Navigator.pop()` this should no longer be the case as the parent stateful widget is now in focus, this is causing my confusion.

**(temporary) Solution**

A temporary solution (which does not give exactly the desired result) is to add a `mounted` check as described [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) with an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887227/flutter-unhandled-exception-setstate-called-after-dispose):

```
if (mounted) {
    setState((){
        // perform actions
    })
}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _RegisterIDPhotosState#b75f9(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
#0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1052:9)
#1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1087:6)
#2      _RegisterIDPhotosState._handleFile (my-awesome-app/viewcontrollers/register/partner/ui_partner_registration_id_photos.dart:103:5)
#3      _RegisterIDPhotosState.pickImageWithModalPopup.<anonymous closure> (package:my-awesome-app/viewcontrollers/register/partner/ui_partner_registration_id_photos.dart:188:23)
#4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
#5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

---

**Question:**

After selecting a file and starting the upload process, how can I call `setState()` as in the example of `_handleFile(XFile?, int)` above?

Comment: Did you try making `onTap: () async{`  or using `statefullBuilder`(may not be needed)?

Answer (score 0):

Refactor that logic to a ChangeNotifier or ValueNotifier higher up in the widget tree and make your Widgets use it to share state between them see [the official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for a more in thorough description.

The setState approach won't work because you are handling 2 different widgets there. You state:

"That being said, after calling Navigator.pop() this should no longer be the case as the parent stateful widget is now in focus, this is causing my confusion."

Whats causing your confusion is that `setState` is not a global callback which is executed in the currently focused Sateful Widget, `setState` is nothing more than executing your callback and calling `markNeedsBuild` for the specific widget in which the setState call was made, which in your case is no longer mounted.

That being said the docs I pointed you to is a recommended way of sharing state in a Flutter app.